# java code regarding grades and averages

Tags: java

For my assignment I have to create a code that reads in 10 assignment grades, and calculates and displays the largest value, the smallest value, and the average. So far, I have been able to get my code to read in the 10 grades and calculate and display the average, however I need help with the part that displays the largest value entered and the smallest value entered.

I believe I will be using if statements for that.

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Have you searched the site or google at all for finding the largest and smallest numbers in a set or array? Are you using arrays?

Comment: Take a look at `Math.min` and `Math.max` to save some time ;)

Comment: Do show us your code, or at least the part you are having trouble with. That way it is easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely not giving you code, but I'll suggest a start.

Set max to 0 and min to something huge, like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

When you read each value, if it's larger than the max, set the max to that value. If it's smaller than the min, set the min to that value.

Answer (score 0):

Have two local variables.

```
int high = 0, lo=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

as your reading in values.

```
if ( value > high ) high = value;
if ( value < low ) low = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I will definitely not provide you with code either, but I will offer an approach to how you *can* do it:

1. Create a `double[]` with a size of 10
2. Read in 10 decimal numbers and assign them at different indexes within the array (index 0 = first input number, index 1 = second input number, index 2 = third input number, etc...)
3. Calculate the average of the array (sum of all elements / size of array)
4. Sort the array (you should probably use bubble sort or `Arrays#sort` if you're allowed)
5. Depending on how you sort it, the smallest value will be at index 0 (or 9) and the largest value will be at index 9 (or 0)
6. Print out the appropriate information

Answer (score 0):

Add all the grades to an int array, then use these functions i've made for you

```
//This will find the largest number in your int array
public static int largestNumber(int[] numbers){
    int largest = numbers[0];  
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++){//for each number in the array
        if(numbers[i] > largest){//Check if that number is larger than the largest int recorded so far
            largest = numbers[i];//If that number is larger, record it to be the largest, and continue on to the next number
        }  
    }  
    return largest;//After checking each number, return the largest in the array
}

//This will find the lowest number in your int array, it works the same way as the last function does
public static int lowestNumber(int[] numbers){  
    int lowest= numbers[0];  
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++){  
        if(numbers[i] < lowest){  
            lowest= numbers[i];  
        }  
    }  
    return lowest;
}
```

Hope this helps you out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the first element of the array as the max and min ..
Then start traversing the array , and compare it with the other array elements.

```
if(a[i]>max)
max=a[i]

if(a[i]<min)
min=a[i]
```

at the end of the loop , you will have your answer